# Move GMail Mailbox to other provider

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I need to first backup and then move a mailbox. Normally i would use OfflineIMAP to download the mails and upload them to the new mailbox.
The problem is I won't get OfflineIMAP to authorize. The "allow IMAP" option is turned on and the "allow less secure applications" doesn't exist anymore. Is this the end of OfflineIMAP and GMail anyway?

So next I tried to use Evolution because it supports maildir format. So that would be my backup and i could use OfflineIMAP to use it to upload it somewhere else.
With my test-account this worked out well but in the case of the customer I'm doing this for, it didn't. In my eyes the problem here is, that my customer bought his GMail account over wix.com. There he also bought his domain (and a lot of other expensive stuff). To be clear: his mail address is xy@hisdomain.com and not xy@gmail.com but when he does his Webmailer is the GMail-Webmailer.

I hope you understand my problem. Thank you.

Comment: You should still be able to generate an 'App Specific Password' in gmail to use an older app.

Comment: I do apologize for this This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of systems should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum or products support.